Apache Hop could not parse xml
1 taking xml https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml
2 execute get data from xml from Apache hop
2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 - The field [filename] contain [C:\tmp\testx\cd_catalog.xml] 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 - ERROR: Unexpected Error : org.apache.hop.core.exception.HopException:  2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 - org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document  : Content is not allowed in prolog. 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 - Error on line 1 of document  : Content is not allowed in prolog. 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 - ERROR: org.apache.hop.core.exception.HopException:  2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 - org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document  : Content is not allowed in prolog. 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 - Error on line 1 of document  : Content is not allowed in prolog. 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -  2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.hop.pipeline.transforms.xml.getxmldata.GetXmlData.setDocument(GetXmlData.java:212) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.hop.pipeline.transforms.xml.getxmldata.GetXmlData.ReadNextString(GetXmlData.java:469) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.hop.pipeline.transforms.xml.getxmldata.GetXmlData.getXmlRowPutRowWithErrorhandling(GetXmlData.java:756) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.hop.pipeline.transforms.xml.getxmldata.GetXmlData.getXmlRow(GetXmlData.java:746) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.hop.pipeline.transforms.xml.getxmldata.GetXmlData.processRow(GetXmlData.java:706) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.hop.pipeline.transform.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:54) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 - Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document  : Content is not allowed in prolog. 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:511) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:408) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.hop.pipeline.transforms.xml.getxmldata.GetXmlData.setDocument(GetXmlData.java:167) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     ... 6 more 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 - Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog. 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:494) 2024/10/04 18:02:41 - Get data from XML.0 -     ... 8 more
tested with/withot bom same result

It's almost certainly the sorts of problems noted in the duplicate links about the XML data, but also make sure you're opening the file you think you're opening and not, for example, reading a filename as if it were XML.
